# Decimal Float Missing Division (C++)

Tags: c++, variables, codeblocks

I am writing a simple calculator program. When I try to make it do a division problem that results in a decimal eg: 1/4 or 10/3, it rounds it to the nearest whole number. How could I fix this?

I have a function that takes two numbers (x and y) and an operation (op) , and returns them:
int getAnswer(int x, int op, int y)

```
int getAnswer(int x, int op, int y)
{
     if (op == 1)
        return x + y;
     if (op == 2)
        return x - y;
     if (op == 3)
        return x * y;
     if (op == 4 && y != 0)
        return x / y;
     if (op == 4 && y == 0)
        return 3293; //When 3293 is returned, an error is displayed (not the best way to handle errors, I know)
     return 3293;
}
```

When I input x as 10, for example, y as 3, and op as 4 (for division), it returns 10/3. My main function assigns the returned value to the variable "result". My main:

```
int main()
{
    int input1 = getValueFromUser();
    int op = getOperationFromUser();
    int input2 = getValueFromUser();
    int result = getAnswer(input1, op, input2 );
    printResult(result);
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

My printResult funcion then prints the result using std::cout, but rather than printing 3.33, it prints 3. So, this leads my to the conclusion that the variable result, has no decimal points. How would I make the variable result have decimal points?

Just in case, my printResult function looks like this:

```
void printResult(int result)
{
    if (result != 3293)
    {
        std::cout << "The answer is: " << result << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "ERR: Can't Calc" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect when you use `int` values? Do you expect `int` values to hold fractions?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik no, i expect them to hold decimals

Comment: Well, unfortunately your expectations will not be met. `int`s have never held decimals. Use `float`s or `double`s.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Can you make an answer showing me how to implement this?

Comment: Make all int double. So division is not integral division and the result has a fractional part.

Comment: "`int`" Where's the floating-point, mate?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your ints to double:

In your getAnswer function:

```
if (op == 4 && y != 0)
        return static_cast<double>(x) / y;
```

Also make sure your getAnswer function returns double...

your result value also needs to be double, the print function should take a double, etc.

Comment: Very verbose. Only one needs casting.

Comment: so when I make my result value double, how would I define the variable?

Comment: double result = getAnswer(input1, op, input2 );

Answer (score 1):

With a int you cant handle floating point numbers, use float or double.
You can cast your int to float for the division.

```
float getAnswer(int x, int y)
{
        return static_cast<float>(x) / static_cast<float>(y);
}

float result = getAnswer(input1, input2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the double type to display the divisions correctly. Otherwise it gets rounded to the integer value. For example 4/3 = 1, not 1.33333

```
double getAnswer(double x, int op, double y)
{
     if (op == 1)
        return x + y;
     if (op == 2)
        return x - y;
     if (op == 3)
        return x * y;
     if (op == 4 && y != 0)
        return x / y;
     if (op == 4 && y == 0)
        return 3293; //When 3293 is returned, an error is displayed (not the best way to handle errors, I know)
     return 3293;
}


int main()
{
    double input1 = getValueFromUser();
    int op = getOperationFromUser();
    double input2 = getValueFromUser();
    double result = getAnswer(input1, op, input2 );
    printResult(result);
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void printResult(double result)
{
    if (result != 3293)
    {
        std::cout << "The answer is: " << result << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "ERR: Can't Calc" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: My getValueFromUser() function works by std::cout << "enter integer" then int input then std::cin >> input then returns input. would I need to make the int input a double input?

Comment: No. You can keep int input in `int getValueFromUser();`  The  `double input1 = getValueFromUser();` line will do conversion for you. You could also say `double input1 =  (double) getValueFromUser();` It is called implicit conversion.